# XHProf for API Side

Tags: php, zend-framework2, profiler, soapserver, xhprof

We have a project with SOAP-client 〉 SOAP-server interaction. Both sides is ZF2 based products we own.

[image: Projects diagram]

We successfully profiling API client side until Zend\Soap\Client::__call. In most cases SOAP request is 90% of "time to wait". So now we looking the way to find out how SQL operation which cost 0.0001s becomes 1s response on soapUI and SOAP-client side.

In other word, how to get XHProf datagram we have on SOAP-Client side `www.apiClient.tld/orderList?debug` if SOAP-Server request is looks like  `www.apiServer.tld/api/order/wsdl`.

What does your project did  to get API profiling data and what is your choice to profie SOAP API Server side?